# Spark Hive Integration issue with eclipse

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive, cloudera-quickstart-vm

i am using cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.12.0-0-virtualbox-disk1 for my BigData practise.

i was trying to integrate spark and hive using a scala code. this scala code is being written in windows eclipse. once the code is written i will create a jar and then pass this jar to my cloudera cluster. from there i will execute this code using spark-submit.

Spark Logic -

```
package sparkhiveintegration_package_spark

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object objSparkHiveIntegration {

    def main(arg:Array[String]):Unit=
    {
    val warehouseLocation = "/user/hive/warehouse/"
     
    val sc = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkHiveIntegrationTest").setMaster("local[*]")
              .set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
              
    val sctxt = new SparkContext(sc)
    
    sctxt.setLogLevel("Error") 

val ssc = SparkSession.builder().config(sc)
                          .enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
                          
    import ssc.implicits._
    
    ssc.sql("use practise")
    val sprk_hve_read_df = ssc.sql("select * from customers")
    sprk_hve_read_df.show()
    
    //sprk_hve_read_df.write.format("csv").option("header","true").mode("overwrite")
    //               .save("user/cloudera/sprk_hive_integration/")       
    }
}
```

Steps i took -

in eclipse i have added the maven dependencies to pom.xml as mentioned in https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/how-to-connect-spark-to-remote-hive/

my spark version is 2.3.1
Dependencies added into eclipse - (i followed the steps mentioned in https://learnjava.co.in/how-to-add-maven-dependencies-via-eclipse/)

i then copy pasted hive-site.xml,core-site.xml,hdfs-site.xml to spark conf directory which is /usr/local/spark/conf/

what i want to do is i have created a database called practise from hive shell using the command `create database database_name` and so on.

i used sqoop job to move a customer table csv file to hive. now my table customer is in practise database under hive. the path is `/user/hive/warehouse/practise.db/customers` and the file is in `/user/hive/warehouse/practise.db/customers/customer.csv`.

when i run the sql statement in `hive select * from practise.customers limit by 10;` it retrieves the data correctly.

so i want the code that i have mentioned above to retrieve the data and then i wanted to perform some transformation, actions joins etc etc and then write it in an avro format to some hdfs location.

my spark-submit command - `spark-submit --master local[*] --class sparkhiveintegration_package_spark.objSparkHiveIntegration /home/cloudera/externalJars/SparkRDDPractiseSession-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

when i run this command i get errors like

```
table or view not found.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchDatabaseException: Database 'practise' not found;
```

Comment: You could run Hive and a latest version of Spark, locally, by the way. Spark 2.3 is almost 7 years old, so you'll need to look at old docs as well for SparkSQL. Also the Cloudera VM is not updated for almost 3-4 years now, so wouldn't be recommended for learning any outdated syntax/patterns... In any case, yes, spark-submit is correct. You'll need to prove to use those tables exist using beeline/hive direct connection

Comment: I thought of that but i am taking this udemy course which is using these versions to teach big data. so far all concepts that is being taught are working fine. Only this section, isnt. i tried to update the spark version and other things to a bit latest but i am getting far more error and vm somehow got corrupted. that the reason i am looking for some resolution with these settings only. it would be of big help for me if this works then i can research more on the basis of this knowledge.

Comment: It's hard to corrupt a VM. You just recreate it... the core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, and hive-site in the Spark conf folder should already have been correct in the VM. Upgrading the Spark version may cause issues only for Spark, since it requires at least Hadoop3.2 now, but the VM runs Hadoop 2.7, I think

Comment: I am fairly new to Hadoop. For now i already have a lot of done in the current set up. for now i am looking for some resolution in this itself.

Comment: Did you need to use Sqoop? Spark can read directly from CSV files. Seems like all you did with sqoop was move an hdfs file, which may have updated the Hive metastore as well. Otherwise [from docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables) 1) try only using SparkSession 2) Grant the OS user account write access to the warehouse dir (`chmod -R 770`).

Comment: while learning sqoop, i imported customer data from mysql into a hdfs.
while learning hive, i created a managed table and pushed this data into table.
i thought as i already have this customer data in hive, rather than experimenting anything else as a start simply read this customer table data through spark using scala. 

Could you please help me with point number 2 - how to "Grant the OS user account write access to the warehouse dir (chmod -R 770)."

Comment: You run `hdfs chmod` command on the warehouse directory you've set in the code

Comment: More specifically, if you're running this spark code as a user other than `hive`, for example, you'll be unable to read data from `/user/hive` HDFS location (causing tables not to be found) ... Therefore, that's not a common location for the warehouse directory since other OS users should be able to access it

Comment: when i ran hdfs chmod, its throwing permission denied. 

Thank you for your replies but as i am very new to all this i am not understanding what hints you are giving and how i have to implement them.

Comment: Query Resolved.